# On Login : java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jms

Our Application runs on web-logic 10. Application developed using java, spring framework, hibernae, jsp...

When try to login in tomcat, there is no error, but when deployed to weblogic server, whatever we do login or try to listen a message from MQ, gives the same exception, which is found by turning on the traces.

What can be causing the issue. Any suggestions are greatly helpful! Thanks in Advance

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkIfRolledBack(JTSConnection.java:178)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkConnection(JTSConnection.java:188)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:93)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:480)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.prepareStatement(JTSConnection.java:486)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:116)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2412)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2875)
   at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:145)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:925)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:738)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:725)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
   at pkg.add.send.msg.InterceptMessageListener$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f327e73b.onMessage(<generated>)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:563)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
   at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1104)
   ... 3 more
```

Comment: I assume: There is an exception occured. This Exception has been caught / handled somewhere inside your method, but it is causing the transaction to be marked as rollback. With Spring you can use something like @Transactional(rollbackFor =XYZ.class) or @Transactional(noRollbackFor=XYZ.class)

Comment: How did you configure the transaction manager (on weblogic and tomcat) ?

Comment: Did you carefully read the logs at startup especially regarding the transaction manager setup ?

Comment: @ben75 Same configuration with different apps works fine. But, will look into it again!

Comment: @ben75 Nothing wrong with the configurations, just checked and compared with other apps as well

Comment: Nothing wrong ... ok then you have some code marking the tx as roolback only (maybe a runtime exception or explicit roolback... look at previous logs !). What's interesting is that it works on tomcat. According the stacktrace : you are mixing JMS and JPA, so you probably have a xa-tx-manager. On Tomcat you have explicitely added some implementation of it, while on weblogic you probably use the xa-tx-manager provided by the container. Double check your config and maybe post it in your question (I don't know what your other apps are doing... are those other apps also mixing JMS and JPA ?).

Comment: Yes all other apps are same JMS and JPA, let me look into all possibilities!